# When I put a batch program in the task scheduler, it didn't finish the whole task, so why did this happen?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, delete-file, forfiles

This problem is from the scheduler task, batch program, or the files in a folder that I want to delete it using the batch program?
and this is the batch program:

```
forfiles /p "D:\nameOfFolder" /s /m *.* /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `/M *.*` by `/M *` to even include files without extension, because [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) treats wildcards differently than most other commands. `/M *` may even be omitted since this is the default setting anyway.

Regard that `forfiles` iterates both files and directories, so you need to exclude the latter, because `del` may try to delete its contents then. Therefore, implement a condition based on the `forfiles`-specific variable `@isdir`.

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "D:\nameOfFolder" /M * /D -7 /C "cmd /D /C if @isdir==FALSE del @path"
```

As a side note, never append a trailing backslash to a (quoted) path, because something like `/P "D:\"` would let the command fail since `\"` constitutes an escaped quotation mark for `forfiles`, ruining the command line. You may however specify `/P "D:\."`.

Comment: I think your answer gives the same results as mine.

Comment: Well, your problem description is very poor! What does *»it didn't finish the whole task«* mean, what does exactly happen? Are there any error messages? How is the task set up? Does the task have sufficient access privileges to delete files? Let me suggest you to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70741943/edit) your question and clarify; otherwise we have to guess…

Comment: I used this batch file for deleting very large files that will take days to delete, so I put it in the task schedular to do it in the weekend and after the weekend I opened the folder to see what happened I found that some files only was deleted not all of them, and I want to know this task did not delete all files because there is a problem in task schedular or the command or the files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you even have such files?

I tried the following (very similar) command:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Temp_Folder" /s /m . /d -7 /c "cmd /c echo @path"
ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
```

One thing I noticed, is that the name of the directory should not end with a backslash:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Temp_Folder"  is working fine.
forfiles /p "C:\Temp_Folder\" is not working.
```

Comment: This batch program worked with me but did not delete all files.

Comment: Nono, it just shows you the name of all the files. In case this works, then you might try to look why your files don't get removed: are there any user permissions which are not correct? Are those files still in use by some program? ...?

Comment: Actually, some files were deleted, I want to know why the batch program did not delete all of them? U understand me?

Comment: When you launch my command, you should see all files you want to delete. When you launch your command, all files should be deleted. In case this does not happen, what are the error messages you see? (Don't launch the batchfiles in a task scheduler, but directly in a command prompt, in order to see the error messages)

Comment: I can't launch it without a task schedular because it takes a long time( the files are very big in size).

Comment: So? I mean, why can't you launch it in a command prompt and see the error messages?

Comment: Because I test it using small files and it works very well but to use it with the big files you should put it in the scheduler task and let it work when you did not work on the pc because it takes a long time, so I cant see the error message.

Comment: Even with big files, you can launch it in commandline. It might take some time, but you'll have the error messages you're looking for.

Comment: A trailing `\ `in the path lets the following `"` be escaped, destroying the whole command line (this is a `forfiles`-specific behaviour)…

Comment: @Lubna, but you are aware what `/D -7` does, aren't you?

Comment: @aschipfl, yes /D -7: for deleting the files older than 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

`.` on its own is not a valid searchmask to supply to `/m`.
You ned to use `*.*` (all)  `*.ext` (the supplied extension) `*string*.*` (files with names containing the string).
`?` is also supported as a searchmask to match any character. example: `*.?a*` would match any file with an extension type with `a` as the second character

Comment: Could you write the whole command? because I did not understand well.

Comment: Well, the asker used `*.*`, which was displayed as `.` due to wrong code formatting. But `*.*` should not be used with `forfiles` since this would exclude files with no extension (yes, `forfiles` treats wildcards differently)…